# Edit indentation in Notepad++ 6.5.5

Tags: tabs, notepad++, indentation, spaces

I installed the last version of Notepad++, and I want to change the indentation from tabs to 2 spaces. In lower versions it was an easier task by just going to settings -> language, but it seems that it got changed and the settings are not same.

Does anyone know how to do this? thank's!

Answer (score 1):

Select `Settings -> Preferences...` from the menubar, then select `Tab Settings` on the left of the dialog.